# Object following an Empty and deforming along a curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I would like to find a simple solution for my animation:

I would like an Empty to follow a Curve + an Object following the Empty and deforming along the Curve, like for example a trail behind a spaceship

If I parent the Object to the Empty and use a Curve modifier for the Object it won't work because the Object will follow a line that is not straight, so it goes away

I could unparent the Object, keep the Curve modifier and synchronize its speed to the speed of the Empty so it would look like it follows, I could also rig bones to my Object, etc... but I was wondering if I was missing a simple solution, keeping the Object parented to the Empty?

What are the simplest solutions to this request?

Thanks a lot in advance!

the file: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49514

[image: picture]